# "Unable to open file for reading" (Swift_IoException) in Laravel Mailable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use Mailable in Laravel.

In developing a new Mailable, I have everything working except attaching an EXISTING file to the mailable.

An error returns as such:

```
   "message": "Unable to open file for reading [/public/storage/shipments/CJ2K4u6S6uluEGd8spOdYgwNkg8NgLFoC6cF6fm5.pdf]",
    "exception": "Swift_IoException",
    "file": "E:\\webserver\\htdocs\\truckin\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\ByteStream\\FileByteStream.php",
    "line": 131,
```

But if you go through the folders and files, there is in fact a file there and I can open it, I can even open it through an ajax popup to view details.

Here is my mailable:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Shipment;
use App\Shipment_Attachment;

class shipmentAttachments extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $shipment, $attachment, $storagePath;

    public function __construct($shipment, $attachment, $storagePath)
    {
        $this->shipment = $shipment;
        $this->attachment = $attachment;
        $this->attachmentFile = '/public'.$storagePath;
        $this->proNumber = $shipment->pro_number;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
         return $this->from('billing@cmxtrucking.com')
                    ->cc('billing@cmxtrucking.com')
                    ->subject('New Attachment(s) - '. $this->proNumber)
                    ->view('emails.shipments.shipmentAttachments',['shipment'=> $this->shipment])
                    ->attach($this->attachmentFile);
    }
}
```

And here is my controller that leads to the mailable:

```
public function attachmentsEmail(Request $request){
        $shipment = Shipment::findOrFail($request->shipmentID);
        $attachment = Shipment_Attachment::findOrFail($request->attachmentID);
        $storagePath = Storage::url($attachment->attachmentPath);
        $email = $request->email;

             Mail::to($email)->send(new shipmentAttachments($shipment, $attachment, $storagePath));  //maybe try to use queue instead of send...        
        return back();
    }
```

So I'm not sure where this could be coming from.

Comment: That error is regularly due to the fact that it cannot find the file you are indicating.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to use public_path() laravel helper function instead of '/public'.

```
$this->attachmentFile = public_path() . '/' . $storagePath;
```

Maybe you need to change this variable in public/index.php. I have right below the require bootstrap:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Make some tests.

```
dd(public_path());
dd(public_path() . '/' . $storagePath);
```

Or maybe verify if file exist with FileSystem class.

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it with the first two lines of your answer, so I appreciate the help!

Comment: Use `storage_path()` if you try to attach files from storage.

Answer (score 2):

I was serching a lot about that, it happens the same when you are tryng to build a PDF on dompdf, just exactly the same, you normaly could write this:

('/image/'.$file) and will not work , so you can solve it adding a dot just behind the rout ".", just like this:

('./image/'.$file)

It works when you want to add a attach in a mail sending or when you want to make a PDF including images in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Storage, and you are trying to export xlsx files, using Laravel Notifications:

in your notification class:

```
public function toMail($notifiable) {
    
    $path = Storage::disk('export')->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting(language_data('Your file is ready', $this->user->language_id).$this->user->name)
        ->line(language_data('Please, check your Email attachments.', $this->user->language_id))
        ->subject(language_data('Export Contacts', $this->user->language_id))
        ->attach($path.$notifiable->filename, [ 'as' => $notifiable->filename, 'mime' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', ])
        ->line(language_data('If you did not request this file, please contact us.', $this->user->language_id));
}
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of /public  we have to use laravel's  helper function **public_path()**

then concatenate actual file path. otherwise the attachment file operation will not work

so your updated code should be like:-

```
  $this->attachmentFile = public_path() . '/' . $storagePath;
```

Most of these errors occur in larval on Ubuntu (Linux).
It may be skipped  in some cases of windows.