# Laravel Mails Swift_IoException Unable to open file for reading

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-queue

There is a similar question here: ["Unable to open file for reading" (Swift_IoException) in Laravel Mailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568739/unable-to-open-file-for-reading-swift-ioexception-in-laravel-mailable)

However the accepted answer doesn't solve my problem.
I also saw the [documentation for attachments](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#attachments)

I am trying to attach file while sending mail and here is my code.

```
 public function build()
    {
        $folder = public_path('/email');
        //Get a list of all of the file names in the folder.
        $files = glob($folder . '/*');
        //dd($files[]);
        
        
        if (!empty($files)) {
            return $this->subject($this->subject)->markdown('mail.newsletter')->with('data', $this->data)->attach(public_path('/email') . $files[0]);
        }else{
            return $this->subject($this->subject)->markdown('mail.newsletter')->with('data', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

I get this error while program enters into if condition.

> Swift_IoException
> Unable to open file for reading [/home/riwaj/Desktop/Project/Library/public/email/home/riwaj/Desktop/Project/Library/public/email/attachment.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this at the root of the project:

```
chmod -R 777 public
```

Comment: Anything else that should be done after this? I did this but the problem still persists